# Debootrap: Non-interactive shell expand PATH variable

Tags: debian, path, debootstrap

I installed debian using debootstrap (debootstrap --arch=amd64 stretch /target http://httpredir.debian.org/debian). When I check my PATH variable i get:

```
ssh git@srv 'echo $PATH'
/usr/bin:/bin
```

How can I expand it and include e.g. /usr/local/bin?

/etc/passwd:

```
git:x:108:112:git version control,,,:/home/git:/bin/sh
```

I already tried the following approaches, but without success because these files are only read for interactive shells. Thanks for advices.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/a1:$PATH"' >> /etc/profile

echo 'PATH="/usr/a2:$PATH"' >> /etc/environment

echo 'export PATH="/usr/a3:$PATH"' >> /home/git/.profile
chown git:git /home/git/.profile

echo 'export PATH="/usr/a4:$PATH"' >> /home/git/.bashrc
chown git:git /home/git/.bashrc

echo 'PATH="/usr/a5:$PATH"' >> /home/git/.ssh/rc
chown git:git /home/git/.ssh/rc

echo 'export PATH="/usr/a6:$PATH"' >> /home/git/.ssh/environment
chown git:git /home/git/.ssh/environment
```

Comment: `I already tried different approaches` -- This vague statement is not helpful. Please [edit] the question and tell us what you tried exactly.

Answer (score 0):

SSH commands like this are not affected by login or interactive environment variables.

This question is similar to the one asked here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332532/how-to-set-path-when-running-a-ssh-command

Try like this:

`echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin" >> ~/.ssh/environment`

Comment: Unfortunately I did not yet find the location where I have to place this export statement. Can you give me further advise?

Comment: That's a command that you run on any shell. You need to add it to your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file if you want it to load automatically.

Comment: I have it already in /etc/profile, /etc/environment, ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc without success. "ssh git@srv 'echo $PATH'" still returns "/usr/bin:/bin"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the problem was that you are pushing commands via SSH. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute commands in a login shell on the remote host, which will process your shell config files (e.g. `~/.profile`, etc):

```
ssh user@host 'exec $SHELL -l -c "echo $PATH; commmand; another-command"'
```

Depending on what you are trying to do, might need to tell `ssh` to create a pseudo-tty:

```
ssh user@host -t 'exec $SHELL -l -c "command-that-needs-tty"'
```